How do you troubleshoot IAP access issues with a GCE load balancer?
I have IAP configured for my GCE LB with an API Gateway backend. I'm getting access denied errors no matter what oauth/iap/audience etc config I'm using.
But my question is not how to fix my specific problem. My question is how I even begin to troubleshoot IAP access issues. Where is this logged? Where do I go to see exactly why IAP rejected a request?
I have LB and backend logging enabled but all I get from that are web access logs.
Logs of type protoPayload.serviceName="iap.googleapis.com" show me nothing with respect to access denied requests.
How do I see why IAP is rejecting users on this LB?

Maybe these IAP audit logs and admin audit logs documents should help you where to start looking for IAP related audit logs including user activity. Check this policy denied logs as well.
